# Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined when using Lit-Element

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, lit-element

I would like to know how to use google analytics event code in lit-element,
When try to debug, getting the error as `Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined` and `Referance Error: ga not defined`.
I have implemented event tracking in the component, but its not working getting the following error,

```
//index.ejs

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js"></script>
    <title>LitElement Example</title>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXX-X"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <service></service>

 <script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', "UA-XXXX-X");
</script>
  </body>

</html>

//lit-component.js
import { LitElement, html, css } from 'https://cdn.pika.dev/lit-element';
export class Services extends LitElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
 }
 handleGA(e){
     ga('click', 'event', {
      eventCategory: 'site',
      eventAction: 'click',
      eventLabel: e.target.id
    });
 }
 render(){
    <p>Welcome To My Site</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="service" @click=${(e)=>this.hanldeGA(e)}>Click Here</button>
  }
}
customElements.define('service', Services);
```